# How to get meta tag content values and average them

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, schema.org, structured-data

I'm working on a website that uses Schema.org microdata for structured content product listings and apparently Google requires an aggregate rating of all the reviews. How can I grab all of the 
`<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="#" />` 
tags and then average them into a variable I can output to:

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="average #" />
  <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="# reviews" />
</div>
```

using JQuery or JavaScript? (Where # = the rating value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is not too difficult using jQuery. This code will grab all the meta contents, convert them to integers, find the average rating, and then append some `HTML` at the bottom of your `head` element.

```
// first gather all the meta elements with an itemprop value of "ratingValue"
var metas = $('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]').get();

// convert the content values of these elements to integers and put them in an array
var ratings = metas.map((m) => ~~m.content);

// calculate and round the average rating value
var average = ~~(ratings.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / ratings.length + 0.5);

// create the HTML for the aggregateRating parent div
var aggregateRating = '<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';

// create ratingValue meta HTML using the average rating
var ratingValue = '<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="average ' + average + '" />';

// create aggregateRating meta HTML using the rating count
var reviewCount = '<meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="' + ratings.length + ' reviews" />';

// combine these strings and a closing tag, then append the HTML to the end of head
$('head').append(aggregateRating + ratingValue + reviewCount + '</div>');
```

or you could even use the Bernard method

```
$('head').append(['<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">', '</div>'].join([
  ['ratingValue', 'average ' + ~~((r = $('meta[itemprop="ratingValue"]').get().map((m) => ~~m.content)).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / r.length + .5)],
  ['reviewCount', r.length + ' reviews']
].map((a, b) => ['<meta itemprop="', '" content="', '">'].map((c, d) => [c, a[d]]))).replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Comment: Thank you Omikes! Your code was very clear and I really appreciate the commented lines. I modified the jQuery to select a specific div id I needed to inject into and append there. Also removed the words "average" and "reviews" - that was partially my fault for including that inside the code example; I just wanted to be clear about what I was asking for, but only needed an integer there. :P

Comment: oops, haha. yeah i guess that makes more sense!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var aggregates = document.querySelectorAll("[itemprop='aggregateRating'");
var scores = 0;
var n = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < aggregates.length; i++) {
  scoreCurr = parseFloat(aggregates[i].querySelector("[itemprop='ratingValue']").getAttribute("content"));
  nCurr = parseFloat(aggregates[i].querySelector("[itemprop='reviewCount']").getAttribute("content"));
  scores += scoreCurr;
  n += nCurr;
}

alert(scores/n);
```

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="35" />
  <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="7" />
</div>

<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="42" />
  <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="10" />
</div>
```